# Test C# Web API app for Windows Azure locally

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

Is there a way where I can develop a Windows Azure locally without having to create a Windows Azure account?

The reason I'm asking is because I am creating a Web API using C# and a frontend technology (I haven't decided which one yet) and I want to use AAD for my authentication using my user's Microsoft account, and want to test it first if my use case is fit for it without having to subscribe to Azure first.

Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question and include more details about what you're trying to accomplish. There are certain things that you can do without creating an Azure account.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. Updated my question.

Comment: Thanks! Why did you add `windows-azure-storage` tag?

Comment: Sorry again, removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding, there are two things you want to accomplish:

1. Build/test a WebAPI using C#.
2. Use AAD to authenticate your users. Your users will sign in using their Microsoft account.

For #1, you really don't need an Azure account. You could simply create a WebApi application using Visual Studio and test it locally. If the intended backend database is SQL Server, then again you can test it locally by installing SQL Express.

For #2, again you don't need to have an Azure account unless your application does something related to Azure (for example, permission to execute Azure Resource Manager API on behalf of the user). If you simply want your users to sign in using their Microsoft account, you could create an application that uses Azure AD v2 endpoint. To create such application, all you need is a Microsoft account for yourself. You can read more about Azure AD v2 here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview.

You would need some place to host your application once you want folks other than you to test the application. At that time you would need an Azure account if you decide to host this application in Azure.

Comment: Again I apologize for lacking details on my question. Thank you for your answer, just last one, I also want to test multi tenant authentication. I will be hosting this later in Azure but I want to test this first locally without having to subscribe in Azure first.

Comment: Multi tenancy could mean a number of things. Can you please describe what you mean by multi-tenant authentication? I thought you want your users to authenticate using Microsoft Account authentication.

Comment: I think i'll just post it in another question. Thanks!